# Visual studio 2008 - how to switch between error window and code window using keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In Visual studio 2008, how to switch between error window (the one that comes up after unsuccessful compile) and code window using keyboard

are there any key combination to switch this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 2003, I can switch to the Task List with <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+K</kbd> or Output with <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+O</kbd> (both of which include errors). I can go to the code by selecting an error (with arrow keys) and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In VB 2008, those shortcuts work but there's also an Error List window whose keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>.